# Starting a remote scheduled task

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

How is it possible to start a scheduled task that is not locally stored but on another computer on your network, using c#?

It seems that i cannot determine the path of the schedule task.
Also I just need to start the task. I dont need to wait for it to finish and I do not need any error handling. Just run the task.

Comment: Probably you could use the [PsExec utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) from PsTools Suite

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Install NuGet package: [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/)
and then you can use:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

using (TaskService tasksrvc = new TaskService(server.Name, login, domain, password))
{
    Task task = tasksrvc.FindTask(taskName);
    task .Run();       
}
```

Comment: Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler namespace does not exist. Is it in another .Net version perhaps?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I totally forgot it was not a native library. It comes from here : http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Comment: Great stuff.  Note you're missing a closing parenthesis: `using (TaskService tasksrvc = new TaskService(server.Name, login, domain, password))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41861081/1117305 helped me, if you're running the task with a user that is not the owner.

Comment: taskscheduler.codeplex.com not found

Answer (score -3):

It is not working because you are missing the using closing brackets

```
using (TaskService tasksrvc = new TaskService("server.Name", "login", 
                                                             "domain", "password"))
{                   
    Task task = tasksrvc.FindTask("taskname");
    task.Run();       
}
```

Thanks.