# Run a scheduled task from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, scheduled-tasks

I am using the following code to execute a Windows Scheduled Task from my web application. Both the web application and the scheduled application runs on the same server.

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe",
        Arguments = "/run /tn StartDataSync",
        UserName = "admin123",
        Password = passwd
    }
};
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Now I would like to run the same scheduled application from a web application running on  another machine in the same network domain. When I researched I found like **I can specify the name or IP address of the remote computer I want to connect to in the /S system argument**. So I tried the following code, but its not working.

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe",
        Arguments = "/run /S 192.168.5.202 /tn StartDataSync",
        UserName = "admin123",
        Password = passwd
    }
};
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: what does `its not working` mean to you?  It means a lot of things to me.  Can you please describe what result you are experiencing

Comment: @Jonesy I am executing this code on the click event of a button. Actually I am not getting any error but the expected Data-Sync application is not running. (Earlier when I run the first code when both things are on the same server, the application was opened successfully)

Comment: I see a little unhappiness with security.  I have also struggled with the above issue.  The below answers are as good as any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this answer ..according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243534/starting-a-remote-scheduled-task)

```
using TaskScheduler;

using (TaskService tasksrvc = new TaskService(server.Name, login, domain, password))
{
    Task task = tasksrvc.FindTask(taskName);
    task .Run();       
}
```

dll for task scheduler can be found here https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler

Comment: Domain name is a mandatory parameter? What if the system is a WORKGROUP machine?

Comment: The code is missing a closing parentheses and edits must be 6 characters long, so use this: `using (TaskService tasksrvc = new TaskService(server.Name, login, domain, password))`

Answer (score 2):

Have considered a different alternative to scheduling the execution of an EXE directly from your web application?

For example, scheduling tasks from within an ASP.NET project is possible using the [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) open source project.

Revalee is a service that allows you to schedule web callbacks to your web application. In your case, you would schedule a callback that would synchronize your data at a specific time. Revalee works very well with tasks that are discrete transactional actions, like updating some database values or sending an automated email message (read: not long running). The code to perform your action would all reside within your app.

To use Revalee, you would:

1. Install the Revalee Service, a Windows Service, on your server. The Windows Service is available in the source code (which you would compile yourself) or in a precompiled version available at the [Revalee website](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com).
2. Use the Revalee client library in your Visual Studio project. (There is an MVC-specific version too.) The client library is available in the source code (which, again, you would compile yourself) or in a precompiled version available via [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Revalee.Client/).
3. You would register a future callback when your code calls the `ScheduleDataSynchronization()` method (this example is assuming that you need your action to run 12 hours from now).

   ```
   private void ScheduleDataSynchronization()
   {
       DateTimeOffset callbackTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(12.0);

       // The callback should be in 12 hours from now
       Uri callbackUrl = new Uri(string.Format("http://mywebapp.com/SyncData.aspx"));

       // Register the callback request with the Revalee service
       RevaleeRegistrar.ScheduleCallback(callbackTime, callbackUrl);
   }
   ```
4. When Revalee calls your application back, your app would perform whatever action you have coded it to do. You do this by adding the following method call (`SynchronizeData()`) to your `SyncData.aspx` page handler, à la:

   ```
   private void SynchronizeData()
   {
       // TODO Lookup the job information and execute the data synchronization
       // ...

       return;
   }
   ```

I hope this helps.

Note: The code example above uses a synchronous version of `ScheduleCallback()`, the Revalee client library also supports asynchronous calls à la:

```
RevaleeRegistrar.ScheduleCallbackAsync(callbackTime, callbackUrl);
```

In case it was not clear above, the Revalee Service is not an external 3rd party online scheduler service, but instead a Windows Service that you install *and* fully control on your own network. It resides and runs on a server of your own choosing, most likely your web server (but this is not a requirement), where it can receive callback registration requests from your ASP.NET application.

<sub>**Disclaimer:** I was one of the developers involved with the Revalee project. To be clear, however, Revalee is free, open source software. The source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SageAnalytic/Revalee).</sub>