# How to pass argument while calling Task Scheduler from c#

Tags: c#, console-application, taskscheduler

Here I have create service for writing .txt file and passing parameter from **Task scheduler** using this code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string abc = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in args)
        {
            abc += item +" ";
        }
        string path = @"D:\GST Project\Demo Text File.txt";
        File.WriteAllText(path, abc);
    }
```

I have added the task in task scheduler like this:
[image: Task scheduler]

I want to call my scheduler task by using C# code below is my code which I have taken from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243534/starting-a-remote-scheduled-task)

```
using (TaskService tasksrvc = new TaskService(server.Name, login, domain, password))
{
    Task task = tasksrvc.FindTask(taskName);
    task.Run();       
}
```

I am wondering here how we can pass the parameter through TaskService. Also 
What should I pass in place of Server.Name,login, domain,Password.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Is the argument the same on every run? Or does it vary from run to run?

Comment: Why call the scheduler task like that? Why not just invoke the console application directly? _Is it because it is running remotely?_

Comment: @mjwills I need to perform every action through scheduler not write code to call exe directly, Also I run it from c# application so I will pass parameter  from c# code. Also it is running remotely

Comment: `I need to perform every action through scheduler not write code to call exe directly` Can you explain why that constraint exists (in your post)? Why do you need to do it that way?

Comment: @mjwills in scheduler I can handle the stop and start but through calling exe I need to kill the process I have not another way to stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below code:-
This will help you

```
TaskService.Instance.AddTask("Test", QuickTriggerType.Daily, "Exe file path", "test");
```

this will schedule your task and pass the **test** argument in your exe file

Comment: Do you know if its posible set start directory with this library? i check in github and i didnt found it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What should I pass in place of Server.Name,login, domain,Password

> serverName - The name of the computer that you want to connect to. If
>   the serverName parameter is empty, then this method will execute on
>   the local computer.
>
> login-The user name that is used during the connection to the
>   computer. If the user is not specified, then the current token is
>   used.
>
> domain - The domain of the user specified in the user parameter.
>
> password-The password that is used to connect to the computer. If the
>   user name and password are not specified, then the current token is
>   used

.

You can use a TaskDefinition  to pass parmeters and other settings. Please try the following for passing the parameters

using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
      {

```
     TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
     td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

     //l fire the task at this time every day
     td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 1 });

     // Create an action that will launch Notepad and you can pass paremeters
     td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

     // Register the task in the root folder
     ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);


  }
```